# empty requests in seleniumwire python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, seleniumwire

I'm using selenium-wire to scrape requests headers in Ubuntu 18.04 and using Firefox driver. But `driver.requests` is empty. what's the problem with me?

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=FireFoxDriverPath, seleniumwire_options={'port': 12345})
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
print(driver.requests)
```

and result is:

```
[]
```

Is there something wrong with Ubuntu settings or Firefox settings or my code?

Comment: Does the website `https://stackoverflow.com/` shows u?

Answer (score 0):

To print the requests you can use the following solution:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=FireFoxDriverPath)
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.path,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
        )
```

Comment: My driver.requests is empty, then actually there is nothing to execute for loop on it. I ran this code on win7 chrome it works good. But on Ubuntu Firefox doesn't work.

Comment: @lord-hasan Unfortunately I don't have a Ubuntu system to test :/ but glad it worked on Windows